# convertir un numero decimal a binario usando una estructura pila en c++

Tags: c++

Este es el avance, pero no se como implementar la estructura while para hacer la conversión de numero decimal a binario, tengo que usar la estructura pila, ya sea dinamica o estatica

```
    //Asignacion de valores para los campos del nodo
    nuevoElemento->numeroEntero = numeroEntero;
    nuevoElemento->siguiente = pilaGeneral;
void binario (int numeroEntero, int resto, int cociente);
{
     while (numeroEntero >=0)
     {
        resto = numeroEntero/2 
     }
}
    //Declaracion de variables
    PilaNumero pilaGeneral;
    int opcion;     
    int numeroEntero;
    int resto;
    int cociente; 
                 cout<< "\n Ingrese un numero entero en Sistema decimal a insertar: "; 
                 cin>> numeroEntero;
                 if(numeroEntero<0);
                 cout<< "\n Numero invalido: ";
                 while (numeroEntero>=0);
                 {
```

Comment: Tienes que hacer una implementación de un *stack* (pila)?. O puedes utilizar una implementación ya existente (como la proveída por `#include <stack>`)?

Comment: tengo que hacer la implementación de un stack. gracias!!

Comment: tendría una posible solución?

Comment: Entonces ¿Cuál es la pregunta? ¿Pasar un número de decimal a binario o implementar una pila?

Comment: es, pasar de un numero decimal a binario, implementado pila

Answer (score 0):

Como ejercicio de mínimos podemos diseñar nuestra pila como:

```
class Pila 
{
public:
    Pila(int capacidad);

    ~Pila();

    void push(int valor);

    int pop();

    bool empty() const;
    
private:

    int _capacidad;
    int _index;
    int * _data;
};
```

No te pongo la implementación porque tampoco es mi intención hacerte la tarea.

Ahora bien, para poder usar este diseño necesitamos conocer de antemano cuántos dígitos va a ocupar nuestro número en binario:

```
int num_digitos = static_cast<int>(log2(numeroEntero)) + 1;
```

Con esto ya podemos hacer la reserva de nuestra pila:

```
Pila pila(num_digitos);
```

Y ya solo queda rellenarla:

```
Pila binario(int numeroEntero)
{
    // Creación de la pila ..

    while (numeroEntero != 0)
    {
        pila.push(numeroEntero % 2);
        numeroEntero /= 2;
    }

    return pila;
}
```

Y ya estaría. Podemos verificar que la conversión es correcta con un bucle:

```
while( !pila.empty() )
{
    std::cout << pila.pop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Suponiendo que ya tienes tu clase pila implementada la conversión a binario es de la siguiente forma**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
using namespace std;
void convertir(int numero) {
   stack<int> pila;
   while(numero > 0) {      // mientras el numero no sea negativo
       int r = numero % 2;  //tomamos el resto haciendo modulo 2
       numero = numero / 2; //dividimos 2 como la conversion clasica a binario
       pila.push(r);        // incertamos el resultado del modulo que seran 1 o 0
   }
   while(!pila.empty()) { //mientras haya elementos en la pila
       int x;
       x = pila.top();   // devolvemos el elemento superior de la pila
       pila.pop();       // removemos el elemento superior
       cout << x;        // vamos imprimiento el numero binario
   }
}
```

Y de tu método principal

```
int main() {
   int valor;
   cout << "Ingresa un numero : ";
   cin >> valor;
   convertir   (valor);
}
```

Por ejemplo si el número a convertir es **5** entonces:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultado : 101